# How to quickly switch virtual environments with virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

Is there a quicker way to `workon` virtual environments in virtualenvwrapper (Python) without typing out the entire name each time? For example, switching by unique id number?

Comment: What index?....

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I am wondering if the virtual environments have unique id/index which I can use with workon, or something similar...

Comment: Have you tried tab completion?

Comment: @Arya - Yes, tried on windows and doesn’t work.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask another question related to tab completion not working on your windows installation.

Comment: While I approve of @Ayra 's sense of humor, I think the issue here is that the environments are in different directories?

Comment: @Arya - For my understanding, is tab completion a built-in feature? It works when I use other commands..

Comment: Tab completion a built-in feature of `bash` and `zsh` shells.

Comment: My answer here (https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/100) might be a starting point..